# shell tool (awk/grep/sed etc) to remove text after number and before a fixed marker

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I have lines with the pattern

```
<positive_integer> <textA(which may include an integer)> | <larger_integer> <textA>
```

For instance:

```
1544 input packet chains processed with length greater than 4 | 1545 input packet chains processed with length greater than 4
```

I'm not sure what whitespace rules there are, may be tab or spaces there. I think the second textA will be the same as the first but maybe there is something in netstat output where that might not be true.
If it helps, I am working on the output of `diff -y fileA fileB` 
where fileA and fileB lines came from `netstat -s` at different times — after a bit of filtering:

```
Based on suggestions better filtering for me is:
netstat -s | awk '/error|length|bad|overflow|failure|dropped|loss|unknown|detect|^[[:lower:]]*:$/ { if ($1!= 0) { $1=$1; print} }'  
(keeping protocol type lines like tcp: ip:, call this the flag, which may be useful.
I hope to prepend this flag to each line (store in variables), and maybe add the
number from the line after the flag which shows the total data of that type.)

Deprecated code was: 
netstat -s | awk '{$1=$1};1' | grep -v "^0" |
grep "error\|length\|bad\|overflow\|failure\|dropped\|loss\|unknown\|detect"
```

I am hunting down network issues...

I'd like to get out (with a simple one-line, pipe-able, OS X command):

```
 1544 | 1545 input packet chains processed with length greater than 4
```

If it's easy and compact in the same command I'd show the data change more clearly as

```
 1544 > 1545 input packet chains processed with length greater than 4
```

This will be compact and readable in log file or on screen...

Is there a better way to get here from fileA and fileB than first `diff -y`?
Or a better way to detect anomalies in my network?

My test file:

```
238 times recovered from bad retransmission using DSACK       | 239 times recovered from bad retransmission using DSACK
17576 dropped due to full socket buffers              | 17593 dropped due to full socket buffers
14016 with data size > data length                | 14057 with data size > data length
3609 packets for unknown/unsupported protocol             | 3610 packets for unknown/unsupported protocol
13562 packets received for unknown multicast group        | 13571 packets received for unknown multicast group
4909 input packet chains processed with length greater than 2 | 4911 input packet chains processed with length greater than 2
1544 input packet chains processed with length greater than 4 | 1545 input packet chains processed with length greater than 4
1473 message too big failures                     | 1481 message too big failures
13 send failures                          | 17 send failures
```

Comment: As an aside, if you were operating line-by-line rather than on a stream or multi-line file it would make sense to use bash's built-in string manipulation primitives (of which it has a quite extensive set). See BashFAQ #100 at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100

Comment: Note that the sequence `awk … | grep … | grep …` is not optimal; you should simply use `awk` to do the whole job.  `awk '/error|length|bad|overflow|failure|dropped|loss|unknown|detect/ { if ($1+0 > 0) { $1=$1; print} }` should do the job, I think.  Using `grep -E 'error|length|…'` (or `egrep` in place of `grep -E`) would be better than what you're doing, too, if that `grep` were necessary at all. The numeric comparison on `$1+0 > 0` will avoid printing lines like `Histogram of error messages to be generated:` — that's in my `netstat -s` output on my Mac.

Comment: My `diff -y` output (a) truncates some messages (`56846 input packet chains processed with length greater than  | 56864 input packet chains processed with length greater than` — dropping the 2 and 4), (b) includes lines with no pipe (indicating no change), and can contain lines with `>` or `<` indicating that a line was added or deleted in the second file.  It isn't immediately obvious where you're filtering out the unchanged lines, or where you filter the lines so you only see the `|`, nor whether you want to process the `<` or `>` lines.

Comment: Very good points, Jonathan. It is useful to know when new lines appear (which would be when a first error occurs as I have previously removed lines starting with zero), the disappear would only happen on first run after a reboot I guess...        
I had also noticed the diff -y truncation but decided I could live with it, is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: @Jonathan: do you run something to do this sort of thing that works better? If so I'd probably accept that as the real answer if you could post it and be interested to exchange observations as I do not understand what I am seeing - but that is perhaps better under my other question as this one was just on the scripting detail.  ALSO if possible I'd also use awk to store the section labels (ip:  udp: etc) and prepend them to lines...

Answer (score 2):

You could use the command

```
$ sed -e 's/\([0-9][0-9]*\).*|/\1 |/' < input-file
```

If `input-file` contains

```
1544 input packet chains processed with length greater than 4 | 1545 input packet chains processed with length greater than 4
```

what you get out will be

```
1544 | 1545 input packet chains processed with length greater than 4
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I had thought of trying to construct a sed like that but not great on grep complexities myself. It's not working for me though - I'll add my test file in a block in the question.  Is it thrown by tabs in the file of reading to end of line rather than the '|' ??

Comment: Using your sed line on the test file above I got back what looks identical to the input. I can't see why but assume it might be reading whole line into the \1 object? I tried escaping the '|' in case it was special and that was no better...

Comment: It works for me on the sample you've posted. What is your OS and sed version?

Comment: Oh, it's OS X. I accidentally used a GNU extension in that sed command. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to inspiration to try this route from awk (above) I have reduced and added to the magic incantations until... tan-tat-ta-TA-taraaa:
`sed 's/\([0-9]*\)[^|]*|/\1 >/'`
I think .* is greedy and runs to line end.
repeated not | works [^|]*
And I have built in my change of | to > for nice formatting my test file rendering as:

```
238 > 239 times recovered from bad retransmission using DSACK
17576 > 17593 dropped due to full socket buffers
14016 > 14057 with data size > data length
3609 >  3610 packets for unknown/unsupported protocol
13562 > 13571 packets received for unknown multicast group
4909 >  4911 input packet chains processed with length greater than 2
1544 >  1545 input packet chains processed with length greater than 4
1473 >  1481 message too big failures
13 >    17 send failures
```

Pretty enough for me! Could not manage to insert a tab char before the >...